# Loop naming in SystemVerilog with Quartus

Tags: system-verilog, quartus

Quartus requires loop naming, even if SystemVerilog does not. Is there a way to avoid it? (I could use ModelSim, but I need Quartus for my FPGA.)

Comment: Please show us some code where you are trying to omit loop name. Unnamed generate loop can't be used in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean generate loop labels?  Labels for For loops within always/inital blocks are optional.

But generate for loop labels are needed to make the hierarchical paths known in case you want to add constraints, ...   Simulators would create a label for unnamed generate loops, something like genblk1, genblk2, ...  But synthesis tools need to create hierarchy properly.

I would suggest you add labels for generate if/case/for all the time.